# File copy *.mp4

Tags: c#, file, copy

Is it possible to copy only *.mp4, *.LRV and *.THM files from one location to another?

I got a c# project where I want to copy some file from a to b.

I got a working methode what is copying my files.. but I want to add some extra stuff to it like the different file extension.

```
    public void Copy1(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
    {                          
        DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
        DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);
        //Gets size of all files present in source folder.
        GetSize(diSource, diTarget);
        maxbytes = maxbytes / 1024;

        progressBar1.Maximum = maxbytes;
        CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
    }
    public void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {

        if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        }
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {

            fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);

            total += (int)fi.Length;

            copied += (int)fi.Length;
            copied /= 1024;
            progressBar1.Step = copied;

            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            label1.Text = (total / 1048576).ToString() + "MB van de " + (maxbytes / 1024).ToString() + "MB gekopieërd";

            label1.Refresh();
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
        }
    }
    public void GetSize(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        }
        foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
        {
            maxbytes += (int)fi.Length;//Size of File
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
        {
            DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir = target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
            GetSize(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);

        }

    }
```

Comment: GetFiles has an overload the takes a Searchpattern http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can get all files in a directory that have one of **multiple allowed extensions** like follows:

```
var extensions = new[] { ".mp4", ".LRV", ".THM" };

var files =  System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
                                .Where(file => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(file).Extension));
```

Comment: @Pasibun: Why did you reject the answer after accepting it for weeks?